# Unexpected index on two variables in PHP form

Tags: php, html, indexing, xampp

So doing a simple registration into database, but the value of `First Name` and `Last Name` is getting unexpected index but account type `username` is fine.

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="signIn.php">

        <h3>Create Your Account</h3>


            Account Type
            <select name="accountType"> 
                    <option>Rentors</option>
                    <option>Homeowners</option>
             </select>

            First Name:                
            <input type="text" name"Fname" size="40">

            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name"Lname" size="40">

            User Name:
            <input type="text" name="username" size="40">

            Password:
            <input type="password" name="password" size="40">


          <input type="submit" name="signInformSubmit" value="SIGN UP">

        </form>
```

PHP code I have tried isset on the `varFirstName` and `varLastName` and still no values in the database.

```
if ( isset($_POST['signInformSubmit']) ) 
{
   $varAccountType = $_POST['accountType'];
   $varFirstName = isset($_POST['Fname']) ? $_POST['Fname']:'';
   $varLastName = isset($_POST['Lname']) ? $_POST['Lname']:'';
   $varUserName = $_POST['username'];
   $varPassword = $_POST['password'];

}
```

/////////////////////connect and insert to database///////////////////

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (accountType, FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
           /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $varAccountType,  $varFirstName, $varLastName, $varUserName, $varPassword);



$stmt->execute();

    /*  explicit close recommended  */
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting, and at which line?

Comment: unexpected index at $varFirstName = isset($_POST['Fname']) ? $_POST['Fname']:'';
   $varLastName = isset($_POST['Lname']) ? $_POST['Lname']:'';

Comment: What you meant by "sssss" in bind_param?

Comment: Try to var_dump($_POST); and look for errors, Or do a foreach($_POST as ......

Answer (score 1):

try

```
name="Lname"
```

not

```
name"Lname"
```

in your html form

Comment: He should also make sure he defines default values for each of the form fields, and only insert into the database if all required fields are completed.

Comment: Haha me 2! great eyes, steven, user4035 and scrblnrd3

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML syntax:

```
 <input type="text" name"Fname" size="40">

Last Name:
<input type="text" name"Lname" size="40">
```

Put '=' after name:

```
<input type="text" name="Fname" size="40">

Last Name:
<input type="text" name="Lname" size="40">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is off. You're never setting anything

```
<input type="text" name"Fname" size="40">

        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name"Lname" size="40">
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="Fname" size="40">

        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="Lname" size="40">
```